# Arrays a partir de consulta

Tags: php

Como se puede hacer en PHP para crear arrays en función de unos intervalos. Hago esta consulta:

```
$code = $params["code"];
$date = $params["date"];
$query="SELECT code, ROUND(value::numeric,4) AS value, time::DATE AS date
    FROM table WHERE dato = 4"; 
            
    if($date){
        $query .= " AND time >= :date::timestamp without time zone AND time < :date::timestamp without time zone";
        $params[":date"] = $date;
    }

    if($code){
        $query .= " AND code = :code";
        $params[":code"] = $code;
    }
    $query .= " ORDER BY time";
    
    if ( $statement = $cnn->prepare( $query ) ) {       
        if( $statement->execute($params) ){
            $rows=array();
            while( $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $dates[]= $resultado['date'];
                $values[]= $resultado['value'];
            }
            if ($rows) {
                //$data["data"] = $rows;
                $data['date'] = $dates;
                $data['value'] = $values;
            } else {
                $data["error"]="No hay resultados";
            }
        }else{
            $data["error"]="Error";
        }
        $statement->closeCursor();
        $conexion = null;
    } else {
        $data["error"]="Error";
    }

    echo json_encode( $data );
```

el resultado que obtengo en el json para las fechas:

```
['2019-10-01', '2019-10-02', '2019-10-03', '2019-10-04', '2019-10-05', '2019-10-06', '2019-10-07', '2019-10-08','2019-10-09', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-11', '2019-10-12', '2019-10-13', '2019-10-14', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-16', '2019-10-17']
```

y para los valores:

```
['0.3184', '0.2609', '0.3374', '0.3538', '0.4762', '0.5146', '0.4106', '0.4505', '0.5262', '0.4736', '0.5749', '0.5772','0.5653', '0.5421', '0.6433', '0.2021', '0.2086']
```

quiero obtener en función de unos intervalos

> 0 <= 0.3
> date1

```
/*date1*/ ['2019-10-02','2019-10-16', '2019-10-17']
/*value1*/ ['0.2609','0.2021', '0.2086']
```

intervalo >= 0.3 <= 0.6

```
/*date2*/ ['2019-10-01', '2019-10-03', '2019-10-04', '2019-10-05', '2019-10-06', '2019-10-07', '2019-10-08', '2019-10-09', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-11', '2019-10-12', '2019-10-13', '2019-10-14']
/*value2*/ ['0.3184', '0.3374', '0.3538', '0.4762', '0.5146', '0.4106', '0.4505', '0.5262', '0.4736','0.5749', '0.5772', '0.5653', '0.5421']
```

y para > 0.6

```
/*date3*/ ['2019-10-15']
/*value3*/ ['0.6433']
```

Tendría que recorrer `$data["data"] = $rows` para cada una de las condiciones, no?

después únicamente los metería en una variable y la leería tal cual.

Comment: ¿Por qué no implementar la lógica de comparación en la misma consulta SQL?

Comment: podrías facilitarme un ejemplo @A.Cedano ?

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
$rows=array(
    "date1" => array(),
    "value1" => array(),
    "date2" => array(),
    "value2" => array(),
    "date3" => array(),
    "value3" => array()
);
while( $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    // validamos que sea menor o igual

    if($resultado['value'] <= 0.3){
        // pusheamos al date1 y al value1
        array_push( $row["date1"], $resultado['date']);
        array_push( $row["value1"], $resultado['value']);
    }
    // validamos que sea mayor y menor a 0.6
    if($resultado['value'] > 0.3 || $resultado['value'] <= 0.6){
        array_push( $row["date2"], $resultado['date']);
        array_push( $row["value2"], $resultado['value']);
    }

    /// validamos que sea mayor a 0.6
    if( $resultado['value'] > 0.6){
        array_push( $row["date3"], $resultado['date']);
        array_push( $row["value3"], $resultado['value']);
    }
}

print_r($rows);
```

Comment: voy a probarlo @Bryno después tendría que hacer el encode para pasarlo a javascript

Comment: me sale un error 500  PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'array_push' (T_STRING) in line 47 ```array_push( $row["value1"], $resultado['value'])``` @Bryro

Comment: notastes que faltaron los punto y coma? debido a que lo hize directo aqui!

Comment: puf, si es cierto... gracias @Bryro ahora lo he entendido.